# Why this iterator is not working in foreach loop?

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to create my own iterator and use this inside a foreach loop. But getting an error that Object can't be Converted from Object to Integer. 
Purpose of this code to understand iterator interface.

```
package com.java.collections;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class Counter implements Iterable {

    int count;

    Counter(int count){
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator iterator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Iterator<Integer>() {
        private int i = 0;
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return i < count;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer next() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            i++;
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    }
}

package com.java.collections;

public class TestCounter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestCounter().test();
    }

    void test() {
        for(Integer i : new Counter(5))
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a generic type with iterable (`Integer` in your case)

```
public class Counter implements Iterable<Integer> {
...
}
```

Comment: did that, got error as "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Iterable to Integer"

Comment: You are most likely trying to return the Iterator instead of the Integer in your next() method.

Comment: Yes Jeff, sorry I typed public class Counter implements Iterable<Iterable> in a hurry. Changed that back to Integer. And it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The Iterable interface can user generics and since your counter is an integer, you should specify this:

```
 public class Counter implements Iterable<Integer> {
    //other methods and code omitted

    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        //same code as in posted question
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

for each requires only `array or Iterable`

Take a look [The enhanced for statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)